# Fulton Algebraic Curves, Exercise 2.32(a).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $R$ be a DVR satisfying the conditions of Problem 2.30. Any $z \in R$ then determines a power series $\lambda_i X^i$. If $\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \dots$ are determined as in Problem 2.30(b). Show that the map $z \mapsto \sum \lambda_i X^i$ is a one-to-one ring homomorphism of $R$ into $k[[x]]$.

Here are the assumptions from Problem 2.30.

> Let $R$ be a DVR with maximal ideal $M$, and quotient field $K$, and suppose a
>   field $k$ is a subring of $R$, and that the composition $k \to R \to R/M$ is an isomorphism of $k$ with $R/M$.

I am confused on how to start this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-James

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is largely ok, but it is very much possible that people capable of answering your question don't have a copy of Fulton (or they keep in their office and cannot peek on a Sunday). Why would you want to restrict the pool of people who can help you by not making your question as self-contained as possible? Here we can guess that $X$ may be a generator of the maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, and $k$ is probably $R/m$ but we leave us guessing :-) Could you please add at least an overview of Problem 2.30? I realize that details of determining the power series may be long.

Comment: the claim as stated after the edit is false, it is probably missing some assumption from exercise 2.30

Comment: Fulton is freely and legally available online: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think this follows from the fact that the $\lambda_i$ are unique as obtained from Problem 2.30(b).

Comment: If the $\lambda_i$ are in fact unique, then *I think* you could develop this into a good answer.

Comment: It is if I remember correctly.. But I'm sure he gets that it's injective from uniqueness.